# C# Selenium Chromedriver only shows 'data'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I created a very simple C# project to test Selenium and Chrome Driver, but when I run it, it gets stuck at the very first line, ie. creating ChromeDriver object.

I have set up as following:

1. .NET Core 3.1 console app (also tried .NET 4.7)
2. Installed Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0 and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.8800.
3. My Chrome version is "Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)". I have double-checked compatibility with Chrome and ChromeDriver.
4. Code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace MyFirstSelenium
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
            chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.jp/");
        }
    }
}
```

[visual studio screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRZQw.png)

`chromedriver.exe` is copied to the debug folder as expected, so I assume the problem is neither compatibility nor path.

[chromedriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq284.png)

When I run the code, the result is an empty window with 'data' in the address bar. No error is thrown. I have searched for several hours and found some articles, but most of them are old and none of these answers led to success.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

---

Added chromedriver.exe verbose console output.

@Piotr M.
[chromedriver console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLEUk.png)

logfile
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ECOS8E55aaTFV63e8P-7n6uRVcf49PRN/view?usp=sharing

New code
Works when I first execute "chromedriver.exe --verbose --log-path=chromedriver.log", but without it, it throws WebDriverException.

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL localhost:9515/session. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.BrowserVersion = "87";
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9515"), chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Could you please open a ChromeDriver.exe with params chromedriver.exe --verbose --log-path=chromedriver.log and initialize WebDriver using constructor
public RemoteWebDriver(Uri remoteAddress, DriverOptions options); where remoteAddress will be http://localhost:9515

And could you provide the logs from ChromeDriver console?

Comment: @Piotr M.
Hi, thanks for your comment. I followed the link below and changed the code. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_client/
Chrome is showing google.
On the console, the same error is repeated three times. What could this mean?
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59592/devtools/browser/fc749e8b-34ab-4586-b43e-2b020a710e32
[4472:26676:0105/214205.314:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [21:42:05.314] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Comment: Have you run ChromeDriver.exe with param --verbose ? If yes, is there any other log in the console? The error you've mentioned is irrelevant in your case.

Comment: I added console output screenshot and log file to the original question. Please have a look inside.

Comment: The log file is the resource that I need the most :) but I cannot download it using the provided link :(

Comment: Sorry, placed the file on google drive and updated the link.

Comment: Ok, I haven't found anything interesting in logs. What bugs me is the 'Aw swap' icon in the 'data' tab of Chrome instance opened by ChromeDriver. Could you check if there are any errors in DevTools  of WebDriver's Chrome instance?

Comment: It seems I can't open developer tools on the Chrome error window that was opened by the Chrome Driver. Right click, shortcut, menu button, all not working.

What I noticed is the following:
1. When I first execute "chromedriver.exe --verbose --log-path=chromedriver.log" and then run the code you provided in the first post(see original question), everything seems to be working. That's why no error in the log.
2.However, when I omit executing "chromedriver.exe --verbose --log-path=chromedriver.log" and just run the code, it throws a new WebDriverException.(error message in the next comment)

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:9515/session. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'

Comment: The error is expected because using constructor that I've mentioned - running instance of ChromeDriver is expected to be available using provided address (localhost:9515) - so you have to run it before run your code.

You cannot open DevTools - that's strange. Looks like ChromeDriver hasn't finish executing js script to perform navigation. That's why you cannot open DevTools - js thread is locked. Hmmm, for now, I'm out of ideas. There is something wrong with your env probably.

Comment: @Piotr M.
I spun up a VM and found out it actually works on that VM. So there was nothing wrong with the code. As you said there must be something wrong with my local pc environment. I reinstalled Chrome, but no luck. Anyway, I guess I will use VM for this purpose. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

### try this code...

```
    ChromeOptions options =new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    options.addArguments("--disable notifications");
    DesiredCapabilities cp=new DesiredCapabilities();
    cp.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    options.merge(cp);

    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Using Python 3.10 & Selenium 4.15.2 I ran into the same issue. Adding the two options mentioned above as: options.add_argument("--remote-allow-origins=*")
  options.add_argument("--disable notifications") worked.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a classic case of cyclic redundancy.

`chrome` is a reserved word, you may have to change the variable name to something else e.g. `chromex`. So your effective line of code will be:

```
ChromeDriver chromex = new ChromeDriver();
```

---

### Additional Consideration

Consider the following aspects aswell:

- Instead of using the `ChromeDriver` class use the `IWebDriver` interface.

  ```
  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  ```
- Instead of the partial url `google.co.jp/` you need to pass the complete url through `GoToUrl()` as follows:

  ```
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://www.google.co.jp/");
  ```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, thanks for your comment.
I quickly tested your suggestion, but still the same. Any other places I can look into?

ChromeDriver chromex = new ChromeDriver();
chromex.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.jp/");

Comment: @ari Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB.  I tried putting "https://", but still the same result.

Comment: @ari Can you delete this current workspace, create a new workspace and run your test?

Comment: I have removed old projects, created new one, installed the same packages. No change. It's such a simple project...
I added a picture of my visual studio screen in my original question. Please could you have a look?

Comment: @ari Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status please.

Comment: I tried IWebDriver, but no change.
I also updated the screenshot of the visual studio screen.

Comment: @ari One last trial, can you try appending a `@` before the url and retest?

Comment: I tried, but no luck. The problem seems that when I set a breakpoint at each line, it stops at the first line, but doesn't continue, i.e. doesn't hit the second line.

Comment: chrome is not a reserved word in c#